# Need some help using Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a system for responding to events that happen in my application, similar to the Observer pattern. In my system, `EventProducer`s trigger events and `EventConsumer`s respond to those events, and the two are connected through a central hub:

For the moment, I'm going to ignore `EventProducer` and focus on `EventHub` and `EventConsumer`:

```
interface EventConsumer<E extends Event> {
    void respondToEvent(E event);
}

class EventHub {
    private HashMap<Class</*event type*/>, HashSet<EventConsumer</*event type*/>>> subscriptions;
    public <E extends Event> void fireEvent(E event) {
        /* For every consumer in the set corresponding to the event type {
            consumer.respondToEvent(event);
        } */
    }
    public <E extends Event> void subscribeToEvent(EventConsumer<E> consumer) {
        /* Insert consumer into the set corresponding to E */
    }
}
```

The problem lies in the declaration of the `HashMap`: I *want* to be able to do something like

```
HashMap<Class<E extends Event>, HashSet<EventConsumer<E>>>
// or
<E extends Event> HashMap<Class<E>, HashSet<EventConsumer<E>>>
```

So that the `EventConsumer` is parameterized by the same type the `Class` is, but the closest I can get is

```
HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, HashSet<EventConsumer<? extends Event>>>
```

But then this would allow things like a `HashSet<EventConsumer<MouseClickEvent>>` being assigned to `Class<KeyPressEvent>`, assuming both `KeyPressEvent` and `MouseClickEvent` subclass `Event`.

A second problem is in `subscribeToEvent`: I need to be able to store the consumer in the correct set corresponding to its event, like in

```
subscriptions.get(E.class).put(consumer)
```

but I cannot get the class of E at run-time.

How can I solve these problems? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the generics from the `EventConsumer` class.  But you'd have to cast the Event object in each implementation of `EventConsumer`.

```
interface EventConsumer {
    void respondToEvent(Event event);
}

class ClickEventConsumer implements EventConsumer {
   public void respondToEvent(Event event){
     ClickEvent ce = (ClickEvent)event;
     //...
   }
}

class EventHub {
  private HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, HashSet<EventConsumer>> subscriptions;

  public void fireEvent(Event event) {
    HashSet<EventConsumer> consumers = subscriptions.get(event.getClass());
    if (consumers != null){
      for (EventConsumer ec : consumers){
        ec.respondToEvent(event);
      }
    }
  }

  public void subscribeToEvent(Class<? extends Event> clazz, EventConsumer consumer) {
    HashSet<EventConsumer> consumers = subscriptions.get(clazz);
    if (consumers == null){
      consumers = new HashSet<EventConsumer>();
      subscriptions.put(clazz, consumers);
    }
    consumers.add(consumer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I like this approach. Originally, I had wanted to be able to do something like `class SomeConsumer implements EventConsumer<EventA>, EventConsumer<EventB>`, but apparently you can't do that (which I guess makes sense). Is there any way I could get some form of `Event` polymorphism on a consumer, to avoid a switch in `respondToEvent`? Like `void respondToEvent(ClickEvent); void respondToEvent(KeyPressEvent);`?

Comment: @AustinHyde I don't know.  I was playing around with that, but I couldn't find a good way to do it without creating all the generics confusion in `EventHub`.  You should also consider the readability of the code.  Even if it does things a little inefficiently, if it's easier to maintain over time, I think it's worth it (unless you are writing a computer game or a search engine or something where every millisecond counts).  To me, all those generics makes the code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to wrap the Map with it's own parameterized class. given the parameter to the class - you can use it in the map. something like that:

```
public class EventsMap<E extends Event> {
    HashMap<Class<E>, HashSet<E>> map;
}
```

As for subscribing - I'll use ty1824's answer..

Comment: Is there any reason I would want to wrap it instead of sub-class it: `class EventsMap<E extends Event> extends HashMap<Class<E>, HashSet<EventConsumer<E>>>`

Comment: @Austin Yes there are: 1. You would make only those methods public that are used by your implementation providing better encapsulation 2. This would allow you to unit test the implementation without unit testing the original HashMap 3. You would stick to the Favour Composition over Inheritance priciple http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @Gandalf Well *that's* an interesting concept that I hadn't thought of. I'll need to look into that more, but I think it could actually even apply to more of this application than what's in this question... Thanks a ton!

Comment: @krakover Wait, doesn't this limit the `EventsMap` to only mapping a single type of event? Because if `E` was e.g. `ClickEvent`, then each key would be `Class<ClickEvent>`, which obviously isn't very useful...

Comment: @Austin FCoI makes testing and first of all unit testing a lot more easy in most cases. But like it is with most programming principles you have to balance the reasons if it makes sens in your special cases.

Answer (score 1):

As for the Map, I'd leave it as follows:

```
HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, Set<EventConsumer<? extends Event>>> subscriptions;
```

And then use parameterized accessor methods like:

```
<E extends Event> void addSubscription(Class<E> eventClass, EventConsumer<? super E> eventConsumer)

<E extends Event> Set<EventConsumer<? super E>> getSubscriptions(Class<E> eventClass)
```

As you already pointed out you cannot obtain the event class at runtime, so you'll need to have it provided by your API users as for example with the method signature of `addSubscription` provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you parameterise your EventHub class? any challanges?

```
interface EventConsumer<E extends Event> {
void respondToEvent(E event);
}

class EventHub<E extends Event> {
 private HashMap<Class<E>, HashSet<EventConsumer<E>>> subscriptions;

 public void fireEvent(E event) {
/*
 * For every consumer in the set corresponding to the event type {
 * consumer.respondToEvent(event); }
 */
  }

  public void subscribeToEvent(EventConsumer<E> consumer) {
  /* Insert consumer into the set corresponding to E */
}
}
```

And then use E in all your function signatures.

**EDIT 1:**
Okay, since i understand your question more clearly, here we go:

your EventConsumer Class can keep an EventType(s) that it supports/handles. EvenType is an Enum. In your Map you store Consumers against a EventType.

Comment: This is not an option, because the `EventHub` needs to handle more than one type of `Event`. If I do `new EventHub<KeyPressEvent>`, then the `EventHub` will only work for `KeyPressEvent`s, not e.g. `MouseClickEvent`

Comment: your EventConsumer Class can keep an EventType(s) that it supports/handles. EvenType is an Enum. In your Map you store Consumers against a EventType.

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting from the end:

First, you can actually obtain generic type parameter type at runtime. It's just that you can only do it in a special case:

```
static class A<E extends EventObject> {
}

static class B extends A<MouseEvent> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(B.class.getGenericSuperclass());
}
```

Note `B` is non-generic, but is inherited from a generic parent.

> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the `Type`
>   object returned must accurately reflect the actual type
>   parameters used in the source code.

Whether you can put it in any use is a different question. I didn't try. Most of the code I saw explicitly pass a `Class` instance as a workaround.

Second, the `Map` here cannot (well, as far as I know) be fixed with generics. You can implement a typesafe map of course, but I think there's one more interesting thing to consider: when you fire an event, you probably want to send it to all who subscribed to this particular event class *and* all who subscribed to its parents. So just `event.getClass()` would be just a little bit less than enough.